# jquery slider not loading through ajax div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, slider

I have a jquery slider that works fine, however when I load it through a ajax targeted div it does not appear visible. My scripts for the ajax and slider are as follows;

AJAX

```
function showSearchOptions(search, distance) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("searchoptions").innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById("searchoptions").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "search.php?ajax=yes&method=options&search=" + search + "&distance=" + distance, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

SLIDER

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider2").slider({
        range: true,
        min: $minprice,
        max: $maxprice,
        values: [$minprice, $maxprice],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val($("#slider2").slider("values", 0));
            $("#amount2").val($("#slider2").slider("values", 1));
            $("#slidervalues").html("&pound;" + $("#slider2").slider("values", 0) + " -     &pound;" + $("#slider2").slider("values", 1));
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider2").slider("values", 0));
    $("#amount2").val($("#slider2").slider("values", 1));
    $("#slidervalues").html("&pound;" + $("#slider2").slider("values", 0) + " -     &pound;" + $("#slider2").slider("values", 1));
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your using jQuery yet performing the ajax request manually?

Comment: consider using jQuery to perform the request, then applying the jQuery above in a callback function. after that, consider cleaning up and optimizing your jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to jquery, could you suggest how I would convert the above javascript ajax code to a jquery. I need to pass the 2 variables into the search.php url as shown above.

Comment: @KaneVincent `$.get(url,{opt1:value1,opt2:value2},function(){/*success callback code*/});`

Comment: **callbacks are your friends**